# iPhone app crash when call self.addChild in CCSprite subclass ..?

Tags: iphone, crash, subclass, ccsprite, addchild

I have downloaded the ABC open source And turning source code into cocos2d 1.01.
Now I'm having problems with the init Sprite Subclass. ( my subclass is @interface OrbSprite : CCSprite )

This Code is endless loop and older cocos2d version.

```
-(id) init {
self = [super init];

if (self)
{
    [self initWithFile:@"bubble1.png"];
    Animation *bub = [Animation animationWithName:@"bubble" delay:0 images:@"bubble1.png", @"bubble2.png", nil];
    self.bubble = bub;
    [bub release];

    [self addAnimation:bubble];

    Label *l = [[Label alloc] initWithString:@"" dimensions:CGSizeMake(45, 45) alignment:UITextAlignmentCenter
                            fontName:@"Arial Rounded MT Bold" fontSize:18];
    self.label = l;
    [l release];

}

return self;  }
```

I search of a solution And can be solved by changing the name of init Method.

```
-(id) initWithBubbleImage { 

if ((self = [super initWithFile :@"bubble1.png"]))
{
    NSLog(@"OrbSprite init in if self Method");

    bubblea = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"bubble1.png",@"bubble2.png",nil];

bub = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:bubblea delay:0 ];
    [[CCAnimationCache sharedAnimationCache] addAnimation:bub name:@"bubbleAnim"];
    self.bubble = bub;
    [bub release];

label = [[CCLabelTTF alloc] initWithString:@"" dimensions:CGSizeMake(45, 45) alignment:UITextAlignmentCenter
                fontName:@"Arial Rounded MT Bold" fontSize:18];
}
return self;  }
```

???? The problem is that when change init name already, I found in " -(void) setLabelStr:(NSString *) str " in the same subclass was error to addChild: in Debug area..
" *** Assertion failure in -[OrbSprite addChild:] " and " Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Argument must be non-nil' "

This is method in same subclass

```
- (void) setLabelStr:(NSString *) str  {
[label setString:str];
[self addChild:label];
[label setAnchorPoint:ccp(0, 13)];  }
```

Anybody help me please.......
Thank you very much.

=====================================================================

## E D I T -- E D I T -- E D I T -- E D I T -- E D I T -- E D I T

I've done this as a reply.
but still don't work
Hear's is .h and .m code

> ### **OrbSprite.h**
>
> this is code

```
#import "cocos2d.h"
@interface OrbSprite : CCSprite   
{
CCLabelTTF *label;
CCAnimation *bubble;
BOOL isBubble;
BOOL isHidden;
int order;

CCSequence *popSequence;   
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) CCLabelTTF *label;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CCSequence *popSequence;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CCAnimation *bubble;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *bubblea;
@property (readwrite) BOOL isBubble;
@property (readwrite) BOOL isHidden;
@property (readwrite) int order;
-(id)initWithBubbleImage;
- (void) pop;
- (void) setLabelStr:(NSString *) str;
- (void) showBubble;
- (void) reset;
@end
```

> ### **OrbSprite.m**
>
> this is code

```
#import "OrbSprite.h"
@implementation OrbSprite
@synthesize bubble;
@synthesize label;
@synthesize isBubble;
@synthesize isHidden;
@synthesize popSequence;
@synthesize order;
@synthesize bubblea;

-(id) initWithBubbleImage { 

if ((self = [super initWithFile:@"bubble1.png"]))
{

    bubblea = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"bubble1.png",@"bubble2.png",nil];

    bubble= [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:bubblea delay:0 ];
    [[CCAnimationCache sharedAnimationCache] addAnimation:bub name:@"bubbleAnim"]; 

    label = [[CCLabelTTF alloc] initWithString:@"" dimensions:CGSizeMake(45, 45)
    alignment:UITextAlignmentCenter fontName:@"Arial Rounded MT Bold" fontSize:18];
    }
return self;
}

- (void) pop {
isBubble = NO;
popSequence = [CCSequence actions:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:.1 scale:.5],
    [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:.1 scale:2], [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self 
    selector:@selector(finishedPopSequence)], nil];
[self runAction:popSequence];
}

- (void) finishedPopSequence {
self.scale = 1;
[self setDisplayFrameWithAnimationName:@"bubble" index:0];  }

- (void) reset  {
self.scale = 1;
[self setDisplayFrameWithAnimationName:@"bubble" index:0]; }

- (void)showBubble  {
    isBubble = YES;
    [self removeChild:label cleanup:NO];
    [self setDisplayFrameWithAnimationName:@"bubbleAnim" index:1];
    self.scale = .5;
    id Orbshowscale = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:1 scale:1.5];
    id Orbshowscale2= [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:.1 scale:1];
    [self runAction:[CCSequence actions:Orbshowscale,Orbshowscale2 , nil]];  }

- (void) setLabelStr:(NSString *) str {
[label setString:str];
[self addChild:label]; //<<< *** Assertion failure in -[OrbSprite addChild:]
[label setAnchorPoint:ccp(0, 13)];  }

@end
```

I already fix over-release problem..
but it still dont' work ..

Also found the same problem is

#### ***Assertion failure in -[OrbSprite addChild:]

#### ***Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Argument must be non-nil'

Thanks to everyone who has kindly ...

Comment: Thanks for your reply
I try to Remove .. but it still error...
what should i do ... Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Looks as if you're over-releasing the variable "bub" in your init method. You don't create it via an alloc or create method call, so you shouldn't be releasing it.

Comment: Thanks for reply..Macro
I try to delete it.
`bubblea = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"bubble1.png",@"bubble2.png",nil];

bub = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:bubblea delay:0 ];
    [[CCAnimationCache sharedAnimationCache] addAnimation:bub name:@"bubbleAnim"];
    self.bubble = bub;
    [bub release];`

But it was also error.
What should I do... THANKS....

Comment: Once again, remove [bub release];

Answer (score 0):

You've assigned `bub` to `self.bubble` and then you release `bub`. Both point to the same address. The same is happening for `self.label`. Try it this way:

```
-(id) init {
self = [super init];

if (self)
{
[self initWithFile:@"bubble1.png"];
Animation *bub = [Animation animationWithName:@"bubble" delay:0 images:@"bubble1.png", @"bubble2.png", nil];
self.bubble = bub;
//[bub release]; <-- This shouldn't be done

[self addAnimation:bubble];

Label *l = [[Label alloc] initWithString:@"" dimensions:CGSizeMake(45, 45) alignment:UITextAlignmentCenter
                        fontName:@"Arial Rounded MT Bold" fontSize:18];
self.label = l;
//[l release]; <-- This shouldn't be done

}
return self;  }
```

**EDIT-** Try this-

```
[self addChild:self.label]; //<<< *** Assertion failure in -[OrbSprite addChild:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Alloc and after that release it.